# Select en java MySQL

Tags: java, mysql

Hago una función para verificar si existe una placa en una tabla:
0 si no existe y 1 si lo encontró.

Sin embargo, no entiendo por qué
me sigue saliendo que sí hay, cuando sólo tengo un registro en la tabla

```
public int buscarplaca(String placa){
    int enco=0;
    Connection cn = sql.Conectar();
    ResultSet rs=null;
    System.out.println(enco);
    String query= "select * from cliente_mensual where placa = '"+placa+"'"; 
    try {
        System.out.println(enco);
        rs = sql.stmt.executeQuery(query);
        rs.first();
        if(rs!=null){
                enco=1;
                System.out.println(enco);
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,ex);
        System.out.println(enco);
        return enco;
    }
    System.out.println(enco);
    return enco;
}
```

Ingreso un dato que no está, pero igualmente devuelve 1.

Los `System.Out.Println` son para verificar lo que sucede con `enco`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se hace la consulta a la base de datos por una placa. Ese resultado se guarda en una clase ResultSet. Esa clase ya no es mas null, así que siempre va a entrar segun lo planteado. Mi solución es tener un contador y si hace el recorrido es porque el valor existe. Caso contrario no existe.

Proba agregando este código después de la ejecución de la consulta:

```
rs = sql.stmt.executeQuery(query);

int count = 0;

while (rs.next()) {
    ++count;
    // Obtener datos de la fila actual y usarlos..
    // recorre hasta encontrar el valor o lo que quieras hacer.
}

if (count == 0) {
    System.out.println("No se encontro un registro");
}
```

Comment: @Mariano ya esta. Se entiende lo que quiero decir?

Comment: @Mariano gracias a vos si que por decirme

Comment: gracias josego, con eso solo agregaba un 'else' , muchas gracias

Answer (score 2):

pues así la consulta no haya encontrado ningún registro el resultset no esta completamente vació como para compararlo con un `null`. lo que en realidad debes hacer el lo siguiente:

```
 public int buscarplaca(String placa) {
        int enco = 0;
        Connection cn = sql.Conectar();
        ResultSet rs = null;
        System.out.println(enco);
        String query = "select * from cliente_mensual where placa = '" + placa + "'";
        try {
            System.out.println(enco);
            rs = sql.stmt.executeQuery(query);      
            if (!rs.next()) {
                 //ResultSet esta vacio
            } else {
                enco = 1;
                System.out.println(enco);
            }

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex);
            System.out.println(enco);
            return enco;
        }
        System.out.println(enco);
        return enco;
    }
```

Comment: Aún más fácil: devolver `select count(*) from ...` y siempre habrá un resultado que será un número.